# Pictures appearing underneath Bootstrap navbar instead of below it

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dom, sass

I'm creating a website using Ruby on Rails and Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6). I have a navbar at the top of the screen, and a picture area (using a stock picture at the moment) positioned beneath it in the HTML document.

**application.html.erb** *(main layout file)*

```
      ...
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
      <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
      ...
  </head>
  <body>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <div class="container">
          <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
          <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      ...
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<div class="center homePicBlock" id="homePicBlockOne">

  <h1 id="homeHeaderText" class="headerText">Simutronix</h1>

  <h2 id="homeSubText" class="subHeaderText">Radical Optimisation Solutions</h2>

  <h3 id="homeSecondSubText" class="miniHeaderText">50 Year Proven Methods</h3>

  <%= link_to "Request Consultation", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<div class="container navbar-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDefault" aria-controls="navbarDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <h5><%= link_to 'Simutronix', home_path, id: "companyName" %></h5>
        <%= image_tag("cogsNewSmall.png") %>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <span id="leftNavLinks">
                    <%= link_to 'Home', home_path %>
                    <%= link_to 'Products and Solutions', products_path %>
                    <%= link_to 'Company Background', background_path %>
                    <%= link_to 'About', about_path %>
                </span>
                <span id="rightNavLinks">
                    <%= link_to 'Help', help_path %>
                    <%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path %>
                </span>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**static_pages.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* home */

#homePicBlockOne {
   background-image: url("businessServicesSmall.jpg"); 
}

.homePicBlock {
   padding: 10px;
}
...
```

**header.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* header */

#logo {
    clear: right;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}

#companyName {
    color: #acb8a9 !important;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.navbar {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    background-color: rgba(251, 250, 250, 0.8);
}

#leftNavLinks {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#rightNavLinks {
    margin-left: 45px;
}

nav {
    a {
        padding-right: 10px;
        li {
           position: relative;
           top: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the picture, **instead of appearing below the navbar, the stock picture is appearing within it**, which isn't what I want.

[image: Simutronix]

While **I could hack around this by relatively positioning the picture div downwards, this isn't what I want to do**, as I am worried it will cause problems for future and unwanted side-effects for different sizes of screen etc. So, what I would like to know is, how do I correctly alter the navbar so other elements appear below it in the document flow?

*Updated in response to offered answer.*

**custom.css**

```
@import 'bootstrap';

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: So u want the 3 gear image to not show there? or the picture with the 3 people.

Comment: The picture with three people should appear below the navbar. The three cog image is the logo, and is part of the navbar.

Comment: My best guess would be to put `home.html.erb` content into a  `<div class="row">  and then it should have a relative possition to the navbar and push it under it and it should be above <div class="center homePicBlock" id="homePicBlockOne">

Comment: I tried placing all the `home.html.erb` content in one div with a class of row but it doesn't work. I also tried adding `<div class="row">` before `<div class="center homePicBlock" id="homePicBlockOne">` but this doesn't work either.

Comment: well, i tried haha well its nice you found the solution tho. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navbar `fixed-top` requires body padding at the top because it's `position:fixed`

```
body {
   padding-top: 60px;
}
```

This is [mentioned in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)..

> Body padding required
>   The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

Comment: And therefore appears outside the normal document flow! Of course!

Comment: No, wait... I looked and I already have that line in custom.scss. Will add to answer.

Comment: I increased the body padding further and now it does work, so this solution was basically right after-all.